# How can I get a list of running queries in specific time range from Snowflake?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm trying to find out running queries(EXECUTION_STATUS = 'RUNNING') in the previous hour to check which queries exceed an hour. So, I tried a query below but I could get only success or fail queries.

```sql
SELECT
    *
FROM
    "SNOWFLAKE"."ACCOUNT_USAGE"."QUERY_HISTORY"
```

I also tried another query according to this [link](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/query_history.html) and found out running queries but the limit(10000 rows) is so low so that I may miss information(my team heavily uses snowflake nowadays).
Is there any way to handle this problem?

Comment: From Query History on the UI, are you not able to list the queries for the specific time?

Comment: When you used the query given in the link you posted, did you filter the results using WHERE clauses? Have you really got more than 10,000 queries in the last hour that are taking more than an hour to run?

Comment: There are some more Audit functions which you can use, Query_history_by_session , Query_history_by_user or Query_history_by_Datawarehouse

Comment: The SNOWFLAKE database is an outbound share from Snowflake to customers. All information there takes time to process at Snowflake and appear in the ACCOUNT_USAGE schema: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage.html#account-usage-views

Comment: @NickW The document says "If no start or end time is specified, the most recent queries are returned, up to the specified limit.". If my understanding is correct, Snowflake fetches rows from the query history up to the limit(in my case 10,000) first, and then applies filters in the WHERE clause.  My organization extensively uses Snowflake, it is possible to exceed 10,000 queries in an hour.

Comment: @SrinathMenon I can see running queries on the History UI. I want to retrieve running queries taking long time and then let my team noticed about that using Airflow and Slack.

Comment: Hi - have you actually tried it, rather than just guessing whether the limit is applied before or after the WHERE clause?

Comment: @NickW Yes, I tried a query below that returned 10,000 rows:
`SELECT * FROM table(my_db.information_schema.query_history(RESULT_LIMIT => 10000)) WHERE start_time > timeadd(hour, -1, current_timestamp)`
However, this query returned nothing - the query has filter to find out queries started more than an hour ago:
`SELECT * FROM table(my_db.information_schema.query_history(RESULT_LIMIT => 10000)) WHERE start_time < timeadd(hour, -1, current_timestamp)`
* FYI: my_db is just an example of real database names.

Answer (score 0):

I get to see the queries in execution with this SQL:

```
select * from table(information_schema.query_history()) order by start_time
```